# Reading a txt file results in unreadable array

Tags: python, arrays, file, txt, writefile

I saved an array containing float data in txt format with the following command

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

Now when I re-open it I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Thus I tried opening it with:

```
with open('file.txt', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
```

But I get an array of unreadable strings, like this:

```
['\x03]q\x00(G?ܤ\x00\x00\x00\x00G?\x1eu\x00\x00\x00G@\x00,G`\x00\x00\x00G@\x0b" \x00\x00\x00G@\x14\x0f= \x00\x00\x00G@\x1ca\x00\x00\x00G@"\x00\x00\x00G@(kp\x00\x00\x00G@.m`\x00\x00\x00G@2\x00\x00\x00G@6|C\x00\x00\x00G@:V\x00\x00\x00G@?H\x1eL\x00\x00\x00G@B\n',
 ',\x00\x00\x00G@Dְ\x00\x00\x00G@G=#x\x00\x00\x00G@JF\x00\x00\x00G@MI\x00\x00\x00G@Pb\x00\x00\x00G@Q3C\x00\x00\x00e.']
```

Is there something I can do, or everything is lost?

Thank you

Comment: can you share an example of `a` ?

Comment: sorry, just found my mistake, I saved as pickle dump, not simple txt file, everything works again